Rearrange rows after comparing the simliar data
I have four columns organized into two pairs. The first pair consists of (Home Team, Away Team), and the second pair is (HomeTeam, AwayTeam). My objective is to align rows where the teams in the first pair exactly match those in the second pair, ensuring they are in the same row. Additionally, when I move data in the columns of the second pair, all corresponding data in subsequent columns should move accordingly.
In the image I shared, in row 4, we have (Tottenham, Southampton) as the first pair. Instead of being in the 4th row, the second pair (Tottenham, Southampton) is currently in the 7th row. To correct this, I need to move the second pair from the 7th row to the 4th row. During this movement, the data in columns (HTHG, First Half Score, HTAG, Home Shot) should also be moved alongside the second pair (HomeTeam, AwayTeam).
It is a bonus if I can get a solution to achieve this using Python as I am learning it and using jupyter notebook. Otherwise, it will also fine if I can get the solution in Google Sheet.


pair_mapping = {(row['HomeTeam'], row['AwayTeam']): idx for idx, row in season_2023_2024.iterrows()}

for idx, row in season_2023_2024.iterrows():
   home_team = row['Home Team']
   away_team = row['Away Team']
   matching_idx = pair_mapping.get((home_team, away_team), None)
   
   # If a matching row is found and it is not the same as the current row, swap them
   if matching_idx is not None and matching_idx != idx:
       # Swap the rows for the second pair columns
       season_2023_2024.loc[matching_idx, ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'HTHG', 'First Half Score', 'HTAG', 'Home Shot']], \
       season_2023_2024.loc[idx, ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'HTHG', 'First Half Score', 'HTAG', 'Home Shot']] = \
       season_2023_2024.loc[idx, ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'HTHG', 'First Half Score', 'HTAG', 'Home Shot']], \
       season_2023_2024.loc[matching_idx, ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'HTHG', 'First Half Score', 'HTAG', 'Home Shot']]

display(HTML(season_2023_2024.to_html(index=False))) ```


Tried this as well:

lookup_table = {}
for i, row in season_2023_2024.iterrows():
   lookup_table[(row['Home_Team'], row['Away_Team'])] = row[['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'HTHG', 'First_Half_Score', 'HTAG', 'Home_Shot']]

for i, row in season_2023_2024.iterrows():
   key = (row['Home_Team'], row['Away_Team'])
   if key in lookup_table:
       for col in ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'HTHG', 'First_Half_Score', 'HTAG', 'Home_Shot']:
           season_2023_2024.at[i, col] = lookup_table[key][col]


You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

I am new in Python, trying to find the solution. I will post my attempt as soon as I will gain some progress.

Currently, I am thinking of using two loops, first on the first couple and second on second couple to compare the same value. When first loop find same value on second loop the second loop will stop and will replace the index. And the first loop will continue.

Your example is not complete, which makes it difficult to answer. It would help if you provided a small example of your data and your desired output. Maybe you can still provide this if my answer is not what you are looking for.
It looks like you have all data in one dataframe and this dataframe contains two columns named 'HomeTeam' and two columns named 'AwayTeam'. If this is the case my suggestion is to either load your data as two seperate datasets, with the first one containing columns E to I and the second one containing columns from K till the last column, or split them after loading the data in the same manner as I suggested.
With these two datasets you can then simply perform a join:
import pandas as pd

data_1 = {
    'HomeTeam': ['TeamA', 'TeamB', 'TeamC', 'TeamD'],
    'AwayTeam': ['TeamB', 'TeamC', 'TeamD', 'TeamA'],
    'HTHG': [1, 0, 2, 1],  # Half Time Home Goals
    'First Half Score': ['1-0', '0-1', '2-2', '1-3'],
    'HTAG': [0, 1, 2, 3],  # Half Time Away Goals
    'Home Shot': [5, 7, 3, 4]
}

data_2 = {
    'HomeTeam': ['TeamC', 'TeamA', 'TeamB', 'TeamD'],
    'AwayTeam': ['TeamD', 'TeamB', 'TeamC', 'TeamA'],
    'XG': [1.2, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5]
}

season_2023_2024_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
season_2023_2024_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
season_2023_2024_1 = season_2023_2024_1.merge(right=season_2023_2024_2, how='inner', on=['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam'])

From your queston it is not clear to me if you want to perform an inner join, or for instance a left join.
On a side note: never use loops in a pandas DataFrame.

For context on the side note, see 'Anti-Pattern #2' here
